# Download contents of SQL Server table, and put the contents in to a CSV file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I have a project which should include a download function whereby when the user press the download button, the contents of the SQL Server table will be downloaded as a csv file.

Is there any way I can do this?

The contents of the table called `Characters` will be downloaded as a csv file. What I know is that I have use the query `Select* from Characters`, but I do not know how to implement it.

```
        protected void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fileName = string.Empty;
        string filepath = Request.MapPath("~/Uploads");// this needs to be changed with the SQL query, but I do not know how to implement it
        string downloadFileName = "Attendance.zip";
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            foreach (GridView row in gvFiles.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                {
                    fileName = (row.FindControl("lblFileName") as Label).Text;
                    zip.AddFile(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(filepath, fileName)), "");
                }
            }
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the code you posted relates to the problem, but here's how you can take the contents of a table and turn it into a CSV file.  The sample assumes you have an already filled DataTable (dtTable):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < dtTable.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    sb.Append(dtTable.Columns[i].ColumnName);
    sb.Append(",");
}

// Remove the trailing ,
sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);

for (int i = 0; i < dtTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < dtTable.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        sb.Append(dtTable.Rows[i][j].ToString());
        sb.Append(",");
    }

    sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
}

string csvFileString = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For performance and economy of resource use, I would use a SQL Command and a forward-only SqlDataReader to get the data.

These articles might help you understand what's required.:

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/2/

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/401/export-to-csv-file/

Answer (score 0):

You havn't told much about your environment. For example:

- Which data access technology do you use ?
- Do you have to escape the fields in your csv file?

For dealing with csv files i recommend using the [filehelpers library](http://www.filehelpers.com/).

If you are free in choosing data access, maybe you should take a look at [LINQ2SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb386976.aspx) or [ADO EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) or just use plain SqlCommand/SqlDataReader.