# Download contents of SQL server tables using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, download

```
 // I want to use the SQL Query SELECT * FROM Table here, how can I do that?      
string filepath = Server.MapPath("test.doc");

 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filepath);

 // Checking if file exists
 if (file.Exists)
 {
// Clear the content of the response
Response.ClearContent();

// LINE1: Add the file name and attachment, which will force the open/cance/save dialog to show, to the header
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);

// Add the file size into the response header
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

// Set the ContentType
Response.ContentType = ReturnExtension(file.Extension.ToLower());

// Write the file into the response (TransmitFile is for ASP.NET 2.0. In ASP.NET 1.1 you have to use WriteFile instead)
Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

// End the response
Response.End();
}
```

Can anyone help me with getting the contents of the table called Table in SQL Server 2008 and downloading it? I have the codes above, but currently it reads from a path, how to make it read from a SELECT query? The query in mind is "SELECT* FROM Table"

Comment: Check out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Cs_CSV_import_export.aspx - has complete sample including source for something like this

Comment: What does your code have to do with a SQL query?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305546/download-contents-of-sql-server-table-and-put-the-contents-in-to-a-csv-file ?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use a SQLDataReader (I'm not going to explain connections etc too here: I assume you've called a database before) and manually concatenate the columns

You'd normally use bcp.exe or perhaps SMO for this.

Comment: @Mark20: just Google SQLDataReader and see how you get on. I'm not writing your entire solution

Comment: @gbn - i so wish we could tag these things with can-i-haz-the-codez ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use SqlDataAdapter to fetch the data and populate a DataTable based on the data:

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Table";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        connection.Open();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            adapter.Fill(table);           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();           
        }
    }
```